# Converting duplicate rows into unique columns, fill with second column values (original df)

Tags: r

I have a `df1`:

```
 Client   Product
    Bob     House
    Bob       Car
   John     Shoes
   John      Food
   John     House
   Mary  Computer
   Mary Furniture
   Mary     Shoes
   Mary   Clothes
```

I need to rearrange-flip it to this `df2`:

```
   Bob  John      Mary
 House Shoes  Computer
   Car  Food Furniture
    NA House     Shoes
    NA    NA   Clothes
```

PS: NAs are placeholders for blank values so it would be a valid data.frame object.

Code for `df`-s:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Client = c("Bob", "Bob", "John", "John", "John",
                            "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary"),
                 Product = c("House", "Car", "Shoes", "Food",
                             "House", "Computer", "Furniture",
                             "Shoes", "Clothes"))

df2 <- data.frame(Bob = c("House", "Car", "NA", "NA"),
                  John = c("Shoes", "Food", "House", "NA"),
                  Mary = c("Computer", "Furniture", "Shoes", "Clothes"))
```

Comment: Typically a row in a data frame consists of related information. How do House / Shoes / Computer in the first row relate to each other? How will you use the data once it is transformed in this way?

Comment: Let's say there is no relation. It is just a table of 3 separate clients and products they purchased. I would like to "flip" every client as a column in a new data.frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R, this can be done using the `reshape` function.  I have to look up how to code it every time - use the examples.

The (much) easier way is to use the `spread` function in the `tidyr` package.

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(one = 1) %>% 
  spread(Client, one)
```

Another option is to just make a list for each individual:

```
list1 <- df1 %>% 
  split(.$Client) %>% 
  map(~ as.character(.$Product))
```

From here, we can add NAs to make the columns of the same length and make it a data frame to get exactly what you want:

```
n <- sapply(list1, length)
list1 %>%
  map(function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max(n) - length(x)))) %>%
  bind_cols()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did try it before posting, it results in an: "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9)". I have a hard time interpreting it...

Comment: @Melissa - `spread()` requires a row identifier, which is missing from the input data.

Comment: Check updates.  It now gives exactly what you're after.